# NHibernate mapping: entity property corresponding to presence of record in another table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm pretty sure what sort of things can be done with NHibernate but I wanted to check with the community on this one.

If I have an entity Foo:

```
public class Foo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool HasRegistered { get; set; }
}
```

I would like the property `HasRegistered` to be true if there is a corresponding record in the `Actions` table (i.e. has the Foo's `Id` as a foreign key and a particular code 'BLAH' in another field), and to be false if there is not.

So, for example, `HasRegistered` would be true if there is an `Action` record  with the following fields:

- `FooId` (equal to the Foo's `Id`)
- `Code` (equal to the value 'BLAH')

Is such mapping possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my knowledge of NHibernate, this is not possible with a "transparent" mapping feature, like **property** or as you can do with **bags** os **sets** and so on..
The simplest way to that is using a **formula** over that **property** and make that property "un-mutable" so the property does'm involve in insert/update scenarios.
hope this helps.

so this could be an example:

```
<property 
      name="HasRegistered" 
      formula="sql formula to evaluate" 
      insert="false" update="false"/>
```

as source of more info about nhibernate mapping features about (**property** in this case) is the following:
[NHibernate mapping: property](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/07/nhibernate-mapping-ltpropertygt.aspx)

Comment: So far as I can tell, you have just told me it IS possible, so long as I can somehow get the entity's Id into the SQL expression (i.e. the formula can be dynamic).

Comment: The expression you can put in the formula is an arbitrary SQL expression (as the link I provided from ayende says), you can put the a Select .... from Actions where Actions.Id = Id (Nhibernate translates this Id prefixyng with the name of the table from the coulumn belongs) and Actions.Code = 'BLAH'. This could be an example, another way is to do it with CASE WHEN, but I think the first one is preferrable because you don't have a set of value to choice but you have a single expression to evaluate IF There's a related record and IF has that CODE VALUE = 'BLAH'

Comment: Thanks. That bit about the Id is what I needed to know.

Comment: The database platform I'm mapping to (Interbase) doesn't have support for CASE WHEN (boo!) but does do correlated subqueries (thank God).

Comment: I was ignoring about your database platform! sorry I told about CASE WHEN automatically considering you were working on SQL SERVER, sorry my mistake!

Comment: It wasn't a criticism, I was just moaning about Interbase's crap SQL support.